# PyCharm / IntelliJ HTTP Client variables not working

Tags: json, rest, intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to use the built-in HTTP client. I set my environment variables by

**http-client.private.env.json**:

```
{
  "dev": {
    "username": "myuser",
    "password": "mypass"
  }
}
```

My **rest-api.http** request:

```
###
POST http://localhost:5111/login
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": {{username}},
  "password": {{password}}
}
```

I run it under the dev environment but the result is this:

```
POST http://localhost:5111/login

HTTP/1.1 400 
content-type: text/html
content-length: 118
date: Sun, 12 Jul 2020 18:01:24 GMT
server: hypercorn-h11

<!doctype html>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
Bad request syntax or unsupported method
        

Response code: 400; Time: 19ms; Content length: 118 bytes
```

If I make the server print the request, it looks like the body is missing:

```
{'_files': None,
 '_form': None,
 '_send_push_promise': functools.partial(<bound method ASGIHTTPConnection._send_push_promise of <quart.asgi.ASGIHTTPConnection object at 0x7fb5ea407eb0>>, <bound method HTTPStream.app_send of <hypercorn.protocol.http_stream.HTTPStream object at 0x7fb5ea420610>>),
 'args': ImmutableMultiDict([]),
 'body': <quart.wrappers.request.Body object at 0x7fb5ea420520>,
 'body_timeout': 60,
 'headers': Headers([('Remote-Addr', '127.0.0.1'), ('Content-Type', 'application/json'), ('Content-Length', '43'), ('Host', 'localhost:5111'), ('Connection', 'Keep-Alive'), ('User-Agent', 'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.7)'), ('Cookie', 'QUART_AUTH=MQ.RDryRo0feBqlOBqjRPyiiUfwxlY'), ('Accept-Encoding', 'gzip,deflate')]),
 'http_version': '1.1',
 'method': 'POST',
 'path': '/do_login',
 'query_string': b'',
 'root_path': '',
 'routing_exception': None,
 'scheme': 'http',
 'scope': {'asgi': {'spec_version': '2.1', 'version': '3.0'},
           'client': ('127.0.0.1', 44320),
           'headers': [(b'content-type', b'application/json'),
                       (b'content-length', b'43'),
                       (b'host', b'localhost:5111'),
                       (b'connection', b'Keep-Alive'),
                       (b'user-agent',
                        b'Apache-HttpClient/4.5.12 (Java/11.0.7)'),
                       (b'cookie',
                        b'QUART_AUTH=MQ.RDryRo0feBqlOBqjRPyiiUfwxlY'),
                       (b'accept-encoding', b'gzip,deflate')],
           'http_version': '1.1',
           'method': 'POST',
           'path': '/do_login',
           'query_string': b'',
           'raw_path': b'/do_login',
           'root_path': '',
           'scheme': 'http',
           'server': ('127.0.0.1', 5111),
           'type': 'http'},
 'url_rule': <QuartRule '/do_login' (OPTIONS, POST) -> do_login>,
 'view_args': {}}
[2020-07-12 14:17:30,355] 127.0.0.1:44320 POST /do_login 1.1 400 118 3759
```

If I instead use string literals, it works fine.

How can I fix or is it a bug?

*PyCharm 2020.1.2*

Comment: The only similar ticket I could find: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-244529

Answer (score 2):

Try to supply environment variable as string like :

```
{
  "email": "{{username}}",
  "password": "{{password}}"
}
```